# Wting reversed function using bisection method in logarithmic run time

Tags: python, math, bisection

I'm trying to write a function that can take any function and return the a parameter that if put in the function, will return answer close to 0 (close to epsilon), the function will look something like this:

```
def solve(f, x0=-10000, x1=10000, epsilon=EPSILON):
```

the x0, x1 are the range in which to look for the answer.
another thing I know is that it applies only to the function that can be both positive and negative ( for example f(X) = x^2+1 is not a good function to solve).

I found an answer here [Bisection method](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bisection_method#Iteration_tasks)

```
def solve(f, x0=-10000, x1=10000, epsilon=EPSILON):
""" return the solution to f in the range between x0 and x1\
use an algorithm to check if a solution can be found so f(x)<epsilon
iterates in a while loop until either a solution is found or if the abs
the value of the midpoint is smaller than epsilon (return None)"""

# make sure the function is in the type that can be solved 
if (f(x1) * f(x0)) >= 0:
    return None

while True:
    mid = (x0 + x1) / 2
    sol = f(mid)
    if abs(sol) < epsilon:
        return mid
    if mid == 0 or (abs(f(x1) - f(x0)) / 2) < epsilon:
        return None
    elif sol * f(x0) < 0:
        x1 = mid
    elif sol * f(x1) < 0:
        x0 = mid
```

***edit:***
so far so good. now I have the main function I need to write - a function that gives the revered value for function. the function itself gets the function that needs to be reversed and an epsilon to which the answer suppose to be close to.

for example, for f(x) = x+2, I want the *inverse_func(f(100))* to return 100.
the hint I have is that I can use the prev function that I showed. I tryied doing so like this:

```
def inverse(g, epsilon=EPSILON):
"""return f s.t. f(g(x)) = x"""

def ret_function(x):
    return find_x(x, g, epsilon)

return ret_function


def find_x(x, g, epsilon):
    x0, x1 = -10000, 1001
    g_sol = x
    sent_epsilone = EPSILON
    while True:
        def f(x):
            g_val = g(x)
            ans = g_sol - g_val
            return ans

        sol = solve(f, x0, x1, sent_epsilone)
        if sol == None:
            pass
        else:
            return sol
        x0, x1 = x0 * 10, x1 * 10
```

what I tried to give *"solve*" function to solve the problem for me. I'm giving it a function that calculates the given value from f(x) minus a value that solve function needs to find.

for example for f(x) = x+2,  then a call to

> minus_func = inverse(g(100)) *=inverse(102)*
>   print(minus_func)
>   is suppos to return
>
> > > 100
> > >       because it the function inside "solve" is 102-f(x) and of course "solve" can find the right value for this.

and I tried this in my code, and it work fine, but not good enough. for some functions, it works fine. but for others, it doesn't work at all.
for the functions:

```
math.e**x
x**-3
```

and probably others, it doesn't work. does someone has an idea how to solve this?.

p.s  - I'm writing the code in python so it'll be great if the answer is also in python. but anything else is ok (I know java also and anything that will explain the logic is, of course, great)

thanks!

Comment: `math.e**x` is always positive. How do you expect to "solve" it?

Comment: x^-3 also doesn't work

Comment: It would be a good idea to provide the reference URL for 'Bisection_method'.  Was that Wikipedia?

Comment: The epsilon calculation should probably be a relative error, not an absolute error.  Suppose epsilon is 1E-6 (one in a million), but the function being evaluated over the range -100..+100 has values between -1E-13 and +1E-13.  Any point in the range is within the absolute epsilon.  Using a condition such as `(abs(f(x1) - f(x0)) / max(abs(f(x1), abs(f(x0)))) < epsilon` would give you a more reasonable answer.

Comment: Also, `math.e**x` doesn't have any zeroes this side of -∞, does it?  With the epsilon, it does eventually get close enough to zero, but it is rather close to the `x**2+1` example.

Comment: Jonathan - I didn't understand exactly why you think the current condition for epsilon will not work?  won't it be to rough of a condition? it will be hard to find a value that will match

Answer (score 1):

The condition

```
if mid == 0 or (abs(f(x1) - f(x0)) / 2) < epsilon:
    return None
```

does not make sense. Why is 0 excluded as a possible root? With the default initial values the method will fail in the first loop. And if the function values are that close, they either have the same sign, which was excluded, or they represent a root of the function since both values are small enough.

It should be replaced by the missing

```
if abs(x1-x0) < epsilon:
    return mid
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this implementation of binary search:

```
def solve(f, x0=-10000, x1=10000, epsilon=EPSILON):
    if f(x0) * f(x1) > 0:  # predicate of binary search
        return None

    while x1 - x0 > epsilon:  # while search interval is bigger than EPS
        mid = (x0 + x1) / 2  # take middle of interval
        sol = f(mid)  # take function value in mid point
        if sol * f(x0) > 0:  # one of roots is located in [mid, x1] interval
            x0 = mid
        else:  # one of roots is located in [x0, mid] interval
            x1 = mid
    return (x0 + x1) / 2
```

Feel free to ask questions about it.